# PHP XML of Google News Feed last 24 hours fetch data

Tags: php, xml, google-news

I would like to use the GoogleNews XML Feed and use some PHP to style it differently for creating morning news summaries.

QUESTIONS

Is it possible to search for a series of phrases in one xml address. Only one phrase needs to match for it to return results, but all are involved in the search?
e.g.. Fiscal+Cliff,US+Debt

The feed url should only fetch the last 24 hours. My query is not. The problem is with the last 2 variables. What needs to be done to fix it.

```
xml = http://news.google.com/news?output=rss&num=100&q=fiscal+cliff&as_drrb=q&as_qdr=d
```

I then want to fetch the `<title>`, `<url>` and if possible `<author>` of each article

Then I want each URL to be used for the PHP to fetch a caption and an image.

```
$item[title], $item[url] $item[author], Item[image_src], Item[caption]
```

I would then echo this information how I want it set up on the page. How do I do this?

Comment: title and url is in `title` and `link` tag. But I doubt about other info. Either you need to invoke another request to `link` url or parse the `description` by HTML parser to retrieve data

Answer (score 0):

http://www.queness.com/post/8743/learn-how-to-read-parse-and-display-xml-data-in-random-order-with-jquery

Use google as this question is not unique and you can use xml dom to fetch, parse and display data.